# FreeMarker in Intellij IDEA: Buint-in string 'contains' highlighted as should have any parameters

Tags: java, html, freemarker

I use the following:

- IDEA -> 2019.1 (Ultimate)
- FreeMarker -> 2.3.29

I believe it is quite straightforward question for freemarker experts.

I need to check if key contains substring, but

```
<#list collection?keys as key>
       <#if key?contains("substring")> //IDEA highlights that "Built-In 'contains' should not have any parameters"
</#list>
```

Do you know why, although the [?contains](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_contains) works any way

Comment: when you run your application, does it work?

Comment: Yes, key?contains works fine when i run application

Answer (score 0):

This is the right implementation and you should not verify the IDEA recognizes its freemarket.

Check more about Intellij and freemarker here

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-data-languages.html